# Stop animation playing automatically

Tags: unity

I've created an animation to animate a swinging mace.

To do this I select the mace object in the scene pane, open the animation pane, and key it at a certain position at 0:00.

I'm prompted to save this animation in my assets folder, which I do, as `maceswing`

I then rotate the mace, move the slider through time and key it in a different position. I move the slider through time again, move the object to the original position and key it.

There are now three things in my assets folder:

[image: assets folder]

maceswing appears to be my animation, but I have no idea what Mace Mace 1 and Mace 2 are. (I've been mucking around trying to get this working so it's possible Mace 1 and Mace 2 are just duplicates of Mace. I still want to know what they are though)

When I play my game, the mace is constantly swinging, even though I didn't apply maceswing to it. I can't stop it. People say there's some kind of tick box to stop it constantly animating but I can't find it.

My mace object only has an `Animator` component:

[image]

Unticking this component doesn't stop the animation playing so I have no idea where the animation is coming from. Or what the `Animator` component actually does.

I don't want this animation constantly playing. I only want it to play once when someone clicks a certain button:

[image: variable set through GUI]

```
var Mace : Transform;
if(Input.GetButtonDown('Fire1')){
    Mace.animation.Play('maceswing');
};
```

Upon clicking the 'Fire1' button, I get this error:

> ```
> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animation' attached to the "Mace" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
> You probably need to add a Animation to the game object "Mace". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
> ```

There is no 'Animation' attached to the "Mace" game object, and yet I can see it swinging away constantly. Infact I can't stop it! So what's causing the animation if the game object doesn't have an 'Animation' attached to it?

**My maceswing animation object:**

[image: animation screen]

Answer (score 1):

When you select a `maceswing` object you should see an Animation Import Settings in your Inspector. There should be an option called `Wrap Mode`, which selects a default animation mode:

- Default - I think it doesn't start the animation, until you do. It's probably what you need now.
- Once - Runs the animation once and sets it back to start.
- Loop - runs your animation as looped.
- Ping Pong - runs your animation as ping-ponged (start->end, then end->start).
- Clamp Forever - Runs your animation once, but it stays at the end.

Comment: Updated question, the maceswing object does not have a wrap mode option, or at least doesn't appear to...

Comment: There seems to be some problem with Mecanim animations, try this solution: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/4-3-0-missing-wrap-mode-dropdown-in-animation-window.212352/#post-1462881 (I didn't test it personally)

Answer (score 0):

To stop the mace from looping (and only swing once when the animation is played), in your last picture there's a checkbox called "Loop Time" (first checkbox). Unclick that.